# Login system issue with while loop C#

Tags: c#, windows, if-statement, while-loop, windows-store-apps

I am developing a windows store app using c# and XAML. when try to code login it gives following issue. Inside the while loop system will not pass to else statement and it will be passing to  `conn.Close();`

how can I solve this issue?

here is my code for the login button

```
    private async void button_login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        string username = usernameInput.Text;
        string password = passwordInput.Password;

        try
        {
            string Query = "SELECT`tbl_user_std`.`user_id`,`tbl_user_std`.`username`,`tbl_user_std`.`pass`FROM `bcasdb`.`tbl_user_std`WHERE `tbl_user_std`.`username` = @UserName AND `tbl_user_std`.`pass` = @Password;";

            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(BC

ASApp.DataModel.DB_CON.connection);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
            MySqlDataReader MyReader;
            conn.Open();                
            bool valid = false;                
            MyReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (MyReader.Read()) 
            {
                if (username == usernameInput.Text & password == passwordInput.Password)
                {                            
                    if (valid = true & this.Frame != null)
                     {
                         this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(StdinfoPage));
                     } 
                }
                else
                {
                    messageBox();
                }                    
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on logic from your code - if there is no user in your database with specified `username` and `password` - then nothing will be returned from server, and loop `while (MyReader.Read())` will not be executed at all, and statement under `else` condition will not be executed too - so you need to handle this case. I don`t think you need loop here, because it should not be two or more users with identical username/password in your database.

Also note other answers about `&&` operator.

Next note.... look at statement `if (valid = true & this.Frame != null)`. I think you mean checking if `valid == true` in this case. Note that c# equality operator is `==` not `=`.

Next note - you have assigned your `valid` variable to `false` and doesnt't change it after it anywhere in your code. So `if (valid == true & this.Frame != null)` condition will never be satisfied. (By the way - it's can be simplified as `if (valid & this.Frame != null))`

Conclusion. It looks like you should change your code fragment with `while` loop to something like this:

```
if (MyReader.Read() 
      && username == usernameInput.Text 
      && password == passwordInput.Password 
      && this.Frame != null
   )
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(StdinfoPage));
else
    messageBox();
```

And I'm not sure about `username == usernameInput.Text && password == passwordInput.Password` check. It is not quite clear from your code but it looks redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You miss a & sign at your if statement, you need to have && for the AND operator.

See this post for more information:
[OR, AND Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848184/or-and-operator)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
if (username == usernameInput.Text & password == passwordInput.Password)
```

with

```
if (username == usernameInput.Text && password == passwordInput.Password)
```

You forgot to use double &'s